# Logout and back to initial application state with react-router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

on the first URL type in the browser my react app with react-router 4 is working properly ant it's is redirecting from `/` to `/fileupload` my code example:

```
<div>
 <AuthButton />
 <Redirect push path="/" to="/fileupload" />
 <Route path="/login" render={(props) => <LogIn {...props} />} />
 <PrivateRoute path="/fileupload" user={FBAuth.currentUser} component={FileUploadForm} />
</div>
```

but if u use `histiry.push('/') or replace('/')` within `AuthButton`

```
goToRoot = () => {
 this.props.history.push('/'); // replace('/');
};
```

initial redirect from bellow

```
<Redirect push path="/" to="/fileupload" />
```

is not working and it is not redirecting the URL to `/fileupload` it stays to `/`

any idea where is the problem ?

if i use `window.location.reload()` or if I refresh the browser all is fine again

there is workaround to this issue and if I just use `this.props.location.pathname` to

```
goToRoot = () => {
  this.props.history.replace(this.props.location.pathname);
 };
```

As my `AuthButton` is wrapped by `withRouter` after logout my `LogIn` component is loaded and all is fine.

But still i'm missing and i don't understand why redirect is not working.

Comment: why not directly push `/fileUpload`

Comment: with suggested approach it is OK and it is working  but `PrivateRoute` and `AuthButton` components is generic and ill like to have more than one  `PrivateRoutes` within my application if i don's find solution ill go with that way thank you

Comment: and i  would really like to understand what is going on and why second redirect isn't working...